# Possible to SSH or Telnet into D-Link Consumer-level routers?

Tags: router, ssh

With stock firmware, is it possible to SSH or Telnet into a consumer-level D-Link router? Specifically, a D-Link DIR-625. I can SSH to my server behind it, but I want to open another port, and I do not want to force a tunnel. If that is the only way, and accessing it through the web browser, then I guess I'll be stuck with that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible. The stock firmware has no shell and there is no known way to put one there without replacing the firmware entirely.

Comment: :( Alright, thought I'd try

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to Telnet.

For D-Link **DIR 600L**

1. Login to the web interface.
2. You can access shell terminal using: `192.168.0.1/shell.asp` where `192.168.0.1` is your IP address of Wi-Fi router.
3. In the shell terminal you type: `telnetd.sh` and press `Apply`.
4. Using telnet client in your PC and type `telnet 192.168.0.1` and you can see login prompt.
5. Enter username:Alphanetworks
6. Password:wrgn35_dlwbr_dir600l

   The username is same for many device, but the password is different.

Comment: Not possible on a DIR-X1860.